# Gitkraken won't install

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, git

Install in the terminal it puts out this:

```
alexeya@RC530:~$ sudo dpkg -i gitkraken-amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package gitkraken.
(Reading database ... 239444 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack gitkraken-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gitkraken (4.0.5) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gitkraken:
gitkraken depends on gconf2; however:
Package gconf2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gitkraken (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
gitkraken
```

I can not run app Gitkraken

There are questions like this one but mine is not the same and has a different error message. I have tried the proposed fixes for the other ones.

Comment: What did you try and what was the outcome? Did you already try installing gconf2? Please [edit] to add details.

Comment: "`Package gconf2 is not installed.`". 1st step: `sudo apt install gconf2`. Then retry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not install individual package with `dpkg -i`. If you are doing so you must to run `sudo apt-get install -f` afterwards.

The better way is to use `apt-get install` for deb-package as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://release.gitkraken.com/linux/gitkraken-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./gitkraken-amd64.deb
```